# How can I catch the output to the console in Prolog to verify it?

Tags: unit-testing, console, prolog, output, plunit

Suppose I have a hello_name.pl:

```
greeting (Name): -
   write ('hello'),
   write (Name),
   writeln ('!').
```

And I want to put in my plunit something like

```
catch_output (greeting ('Moncho'), ConsoleOutput),
  assertion ('hello Moncho!' =:= ConsoleOutput).
```

Comment: Just as an addendum, do not use `write` (it is meant so serialize-out terms), use `format`. I have prepared a little overview on "printing in Prolog" [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/dtonhofer/20bd01f68a924912771d8405fca66a09) (Work in progress).

Comment: @DavidTonhofer thank you sir, I added your link in the [Codewars kata I've created](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57036f007fd72e3b77000023)

Comment: Of interest: [Help with set_prolog_IO/3](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/help-with-set-prolog-io-3/1798)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog)

See: [with_output_to/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=with_output_to/2)

Note: with_output_to/2 is [implemented using C](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/cb25bef5cb6d3ecc96d435e160e7dcbc406d1287/src/os/pl-file.c#L1567) in SWI-Prolog so is not portable as Prolog code.

```
?- with_output_to(string(Output),(write('hello'),write('Rusian'),write('!'))), 
   assertion( Output == "helloRusian!").
```

With corrections to your code and using [SWI-Prolog unit tests](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27))

```
greeting(Name) :-
   write('hello'),
   write(Name),
   writeln('!').

:- begin_tests(your_tests).

test(001, Output == 'helloMoncho!\n') :-
    with_output_to(atom(Output), greeting('Moncho')).

:- end_tests(your_tests).
```